# Issue with logout button

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to implement Facebook Connect login on my web page, and below you have my (poor) try so far.

- If being logged out the login button is shown, as supposed.
- If clicking the login button the Facebook login popup window appears, as supposed.
- If loggin in the popup window disappears, the user gets logged in and the button changes to a logout button.
- If clicking the logout button the user gets logged out, BUT!:

  1. The button doesn't get changed to a login button.
  2. Sometimes up to three popup windows (login) opens up.
  3. The function testAPI() gets executed.
  4. Sometimes the following error message is shown in the console: "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

**JS:**

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        showLogoutButton();
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        showLoginButton();
      } else {
        showLoginButton();
      }
     });
  };

  function showLoginButton() {
    $('#FBButtonDiv').show();

    $('#FBButton').html('Log in Facebook');
    $('#FBButton').on('click', function(){
      login();
    });
  }

  function showLogoutButton() {
    $('#FBButtonDiv').show();

    $('#FBButton').html('Log out Facebook');
    $('#FBButton').on('click', function(){
      logout();
    });
  }

  function login() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
              // connected
              testAPI();
              showLogoutButton();
          } else {
              // cancelled
          }
      });
  }

  function logout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
      showLogoutButton();
    });
  }

  function testAPI() {
      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      });
  }

  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<div id="FBButtonDiv"><button id="FBButton">Facebook login!</button></div>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
#FBButtonDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

So, what can be wrong in my code?

Note: I know the code contains of alot of DRY but I'll do alot of refactoring when I get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly my speciality, JS/FB-API but I would guess:

```
function logout() {
  FB.logout(function(response) {
    showLogoutButton();
  });
}
```

Should be:

```
function logout() {
   FB.logout(function(response) {
     showLoginButton();
   });
}
```

Because after the response is recieved, the callback should be to show the login button to the now logged out user. Of course you should probably check the response similarly to login to confirm the logout was succesful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, totally missed that :-) Do you have any other ideas regarding the error message as well as the popup window is loaded 2-3 times sometimes?

Comment: As a pure guess I would check the jQuery API to see whether you are actually registering multiple onClick() handlers rather than replacing the last one.